# how to escape curly braces in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

I have ***data*** in my ***database*** that may contains curly braces`{{ }}`.

```
{{-- inside app.blade.php --}}
<!-- vue app -->
<div id="app">
    ...code
    <div> {{ $data }} </div>
    ...code
</div>
```

so if I want to display it to the user this data cause problem if it's inside Vue app. and vue think it's javascript codes to execute.

for example if the `$data` is equal to `{{ title->links() }}` then I get an error and the whole app doesn't compile at all. (it passes the blade template).

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: expected expression, got '>' in

    _s(title->links())

  Raw expression: {{ title->links() }}

305|              <div>{{ title-&gt;links() }}</div>
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

what is the best way to escape `{{ }}` curly braces for user data (in Vue.js)??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need use the [`v-pre`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre) or `v-html` directive:

```html
<div v-pre>{{ data }}</div>
```

or

```html
<div v-html="'{{ data }}'"></div>
```

Comment: u r in `app.blade.php ` so when both vuejs and laravel try to compile  so u need to tell laravel ignore this

Comment: @{{ $data }} will ignore the whole data. I want to show it to the user not hiding it.

Comment: can u put where  are adding `$data`.?

Comment: $data is a variable that comes from the `database` and it's the `user input`. that may contains curly braces. it passes the blade template but not vue template.

Comment: so basically . `$data` have html or row text .?